# How to extract Twitter usernames from a tweet using Javascript

Tags: javascript, string, parsing, twitter

I want to use Javascript to parse a tweet and return an array containing the people mentioned in that tweet. Twitter usernames all begin with @. Assuming that I already have the string, how can this be done?

Comment: any full source code sample html-javascript?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var tweet = "hello to @you and @him!";
var users = tweet.match(/@\w+/g);
console.log(users); // Will return an array containing ["@you", "@him"]
```

Then, you can strip the `@` to only get the names:

```
for (userIndex = 0; userIndex < users.length; userIndex++)
    users[userIndex] = users[userIndex].substr(1);
```

Which will then return the array as

```
["you", "him"]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
​var tweet = 'This tweet is for @me and @you #hashtag';
var matches = tweet.match(/@\w+/g);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9QLbb/