# how to parse a JS usernames?

Tags: javascript, regex

My string is:

```
"@john @jerry @kerry hello world"
```

My goal is to obtain an array:

```
["john","jerry","kerry", "hello world"];
```

Infact @ is the marker for username and the last array item is the rest of the string.

Any idea ?

Comment: So the username will just be on the beginning of the string? No username in the middle or end? Right?

Comment: `"@john @jerry @kerry hello world".split(/@(\w+)\s+/g).filter(Boolean)`

Comment: This could be a start: http://stackoverflow.com/q/9665279/218196

Answer (score 1):

You can take the rest of the string and after that you can extract users and to append last string in array.

```
var data = "@john @jerry @kerry hello world";
// get rest of the string
var lastString = data.match(/ \w+/g).join('').trim();
// get users
var array = data.match(/@\w+/g).join('').split('@');
array = array.slice(1,array.length);
// add rest of string to end of array
array.push(lastString);
```

```js
var data = "@john @jerry @kerry hello world";
// get rest of the string
var lastString = data.match(/ \w+/g).join('').trim();
// get users
var array = data.match(/@\w+/g).join('').split('@');
array = array.slice(1,array.length);
// add rest of string to end of array
array.push(lastString);

alert(array);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use following regex :

```
var str = "@john @jerry @kerry hello world";
var list = str.split(/(@\w+)/);
```

```js
var str = "@john @jerry @kerry hello world";
var list = str.split(/(@\w+)/);
alert(list);
```